# Using libexempi on AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use simple python handler on AWS lambda which uses libxmp.
It fails on initialization: **from libxmp import XMPFiles, consts**

I have compiled (on 64bit AMI linux instance) exempi-2.4.2 and placed in under TASK_ROOT/lib in bundle.zip. But still getting:

```
Exempi library not found.: ExempiLoadError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 11, in handler
    from libxmp import XMPFiles, consts
  File "/var/task/libxmp/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .core import XMPMeta, XMPIterator
  File "/var/task/libxmp/core.py", line 50, in <module>
    from . import exempi as _cexempi
  File "/var/task/libxmp/exempi.py", line 70, in <module>
    EXEMPI = _load_exempi()
  File "/var/task/libxmp/exempi.py", line 61, in _load_exempi
    raise ExempiLoadError('Exempi library not found.')
ExempiLoadError: Exempi library not found.
```

Comment: I'm facing that exact same thing and getting nowhere. Tried a ton of variations, i'm not sure what the problem is. Did you get anywhere with it, @andjelx?

Comment: No unfortunately no luck

Comment: you can use a [Lambda Container Image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-images.html?icmpid=docs_lambda_help) and make sure to run `$ yum install exempi -y`.